# can we use UIAutomator in android applications?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I want to know can we use UIAutomator in our applications ? 
I want write an app that open another application, write some Text in that application EditText and then press some buttons (like open Hangout and write a text on it and send the message). 
Can you suggest me how can I do this?

I have searched the net and I could only find out I can test my UI with UIAutomator, but I don't know if I can use it to write an Android application (not jar file) and run it on my Android device to do this.

Comment: Have you ever used `UIAutomator`? It is a local tool to automate testing locally on your machine. The best thing you can do is send data through intents.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Can i use intents for any applications? I means can i use it for access the application somebody else make it? ( like viber)

Comment: Does viber accept intents? That's another question. Google if Viber has an api.

Comment: Any luck with your effort. I'm trying to do something very similar and would like to know if this is actually possible

Comment: I couldn't do anything with that, i think its not possible using this method. the source application must be granted you access.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't possible.

UiAutomator 2.0 relies on [Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#Instrumentation) which is only available when you run your test using `am instrument ...`. Regular (non-test) apps don't have access to Instrumentation.

Shell-based UiAutomator is similar. You execute tests using `adb shell uiautomator runtest ...` and UiAutomatorTestRunner takes advantage of the fact that it is running as the shell user to do things that normal apps don't have permission to do.

If you use `Runtime#exec(..)` to call either `am instrument` or `uiautomator runtest`, the command won't run as the shell user (it will use your application's uid), and will fail because it doesn't have the necessary permissions.

Comment: Thanks  , is there anyway to do some action in other program without intent permisions ? .. like check 1 number have viber account or not by enter his number in our app ?

Comment: Nope. Apps run in isolation from each other, and the only way to interact with another app is through the interfaces that it exposes. If the app doesn't expose an interface for you to use, then you're out of luck.

Comment: Is it possible to run the app with shell permissions or shell UID. Can we register to some permission in Manifest to do that? I'm trying to do the same thing on a rooted device, so, is it possible to do the same thing by registering to some permissions?