# How to run UiAutomator from MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I am implementing UiAutomator for my application for cross-app UI automation. I've put it under AndroidTest class. It works fine when I run my test class but I need it to be running from my app (not having to connect it to the computer). 
I found this solution but it is not working:

```
 private void runTests() {
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    final String packageName = getPackageName();
    final List<InstrumentationInfo> list =
            getPackageManager().queryInstrumentation(packageName, 0);
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    final InstrumentationInfo instrumentationInfo = list.get(0);
    final ComponentName componentName =
            new ComponentName(instrumentationInfo.packageName,
                    instrumentationInfo.name);

    arguments.putString("package",  "my package");
    startInstrumentation(componentName,null,arguments);
   }
```

Apparently the UiAutomator argument of the instrumentation is returned null. Any idea how run UiAutomator from the main application?

Comment: "It works fine when I run my test class but I need it to be running from my app (not having to connect it to the computer)" -- you cannot run instrumentation tests that way. They have to be run by a test runner, from a suitable process. "I am implementing UiAutomator for my application for cross-app UI automation" -- you may wish to explain in greater detail what you mean by this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. See this answer to a similar question:

> UiAutomator 2.0 relies on Instrumentation which is only available when you run your test using am instrument .... Regular (non-test) apps don't have access to Instrumentation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29419540/1999084