# Android: UIAutomator in a production app?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

Is there anything that would prevent me from using UIAutomator in the *implementation* of an app released to the Android app store?

My goal is to automate some simple user interaction of a third party's app from my app. This requires introspection of, and interaction with third party apps. From my (limited) research, UIAutomator is the most general purpose way to accomplish this type of task.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything that would prevent me from using UIAutomator in the implementation of an app released to the Android app store?

Well, there's the fact that it will not work, except perhaps on rooted devices.

> My goal is to automate some simple user interaction of a third party's app from my app. This requires introspection of, and interaction with third party apps.

Fortunately, this is not possible in general, for obvious security reasons (e.g., automatically bypassing security dialogs).

Comment: "it will not work" is so vague. What exactly is the failure mode?

Comment: @bukzor: Presumably either a `NullPointerException` or a `SecurityException`, assuming that you can even find some syntax that can compile outside of test code. `UiAutomation` is for testing and can only be used in test code as a result.

Comment: @bukzor See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29419540/1999084 for a more detailed response to a similar question. CommonsWare is right however.