# Can we use API for testing inside Android Activities or classes?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

Can we use android test API (like simulating touch events) from frameworks like UIAutomator or Espresso inside our android code in Activities. I'm new to android, please clarify.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why do you need to write tests inside of the UI? Your tests should read and interact separately from those classes.

Comment: i want to simulate touch event on another app which is called via intent so thought of using these classes inside an Activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can we use UIAutomator in android applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401098/can-we-use-uiautomator-in-android-applications)

Answer (score 0):

> Can we use android test API (like simulating touch events) from frameworks like UIAutomator or Espresso inside our android code in Activities.

Not normally. Such tests need to be run under a special account; your app will not be associated with such an account. As usual, I cannot rule out specialized scenarios (rooted devices, custom ROMs, etc.).

Comment: I have a rooted device @CommonsWare

Comment: @Abhi: I still doubt that you can use the classes inside of your `Activity`. I would guess that you could use `su` (or whatever) to run test code, though, the way that you can with the Android SDK.